# JSON to BSON conversion is done on mongo client or mongod server?

Tags: mongodb

In monogdb the JSON to BSON conversion during write operations and vice versa during read operations is done on MongoClient (shell or drivers) or the mongod server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB clients(Shell and Driver) change the JSON to BSON or vice versa, Driver/Shell communicate with mongoDB in BSON format.

You can check below video by mongodb university explaining this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCjpSq7H_G4